# Java: Apply different textures to cube faces and render image to png with JOGL

Tags: java, jogl

I want to render a cube with three faces visible, each of those faces should have a different texture applied to it, which should be easily interchangable. I managed to get this basic code running, that only works with colors.

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

import static com.jogamp.opengl.GL.GL_MULTISAMPLE;

public class CubeRenderer extends GLJPanel implements GLEventListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("JOGL Scene");
        GLCapabilities caps = new GLCapabilities(null);
        CubeRenderer panel = new CubeRenderer(caps);
        window.setContentPane(panel);
        window.pack();
        window.setLocation(50,50);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setVisible(true);
        panel.requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    private final float rotateX;
    private final float rotateY;
    private final float rotateZ;   // rotation amounts about axes
    private int texture;

    // Correct orientation -45.0, 150.0, 90.0
    public CubeRenderer(GLCapabilities capabilities) {
        super(capabilities);
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(500,500) );
        addGLEventListener(this);
        rotateX = -45.0f;
        rotateY = 150.0f;
        rotateZ = 90.0f;
    }

    private void square(GL2 gl, float r, float g, float b) {
        gl.glColor3f(r,g,b);         // The color for the square.
        gl.glTranslatef(0,0,0.5f);    // Move square 0.5 units forward.
        gl.glNormal3f(0,0,1);        // Normal vector to square (this is actually the default).
        gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        gl.glVertex2f(-0.5f,-0.5f);    // Draw the square (before the
        gl.glVertex2f(0.5f,-0.5f);     //   the translation is applied)
        gl.glVertex2f(0.5f,0.5f);      //   on the xy-plane, with its
        gl.glVertex2f(-0.5f,0.5f);     //   at (0,0,0).
        gl.glEnd();
    }

    private void cube(GL2 gl) {


        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(180,0,1,0); // rotate square to back face
        square(gl,0,1,1);        // back face is cyan
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(-90,0,1,0); // rotate square to left face
        square(gl,0,1,0);        // left face is green
        gl.glPopMatrix();

        gl.glPushMatrix();
        gl.glRotatef(-90,1,0,0); // rotate square to top face
        square(gl,0,0,1);        // top face is blue
        gl.glPopMatrix();
    }

    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // called when the panel needs to be drawn

        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
        gl.glClear( GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_PROJECTION);  // Set up the projection.
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrtho(-1,1,-1,1,-2,2);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL2.GL_MODELVIEW);

        gl.glLoadIdentity();             // Set up modelview transform.
        gl.glRotatef(rotateZ,0,0,1);
        gl.glRotatef(rotateY,0,1,0);
        gl.glRotatef(rotateX,1,0,0);

        cube(gl);

    }

    public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // called when the panel is created
        GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
        gl.glClearColor(0.8F, 0.8F, 0.8F, 1.0F);
        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHTING);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_LIGHT0);
        gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);
        gl.glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
    }

    public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
        // called when the panel is being disposed
    }

    public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        // called when user resizes the window
    }

}
```

I however could not figure out how to apply texture instead of colors and how to then render  the whole cube into a png, as I could not get any of these tutorials to run, as most of them were quite old.

Answer (score 0):

Either merge the 3 images into a single image, create a single texture, bind it, enable texture target and use your texture as a texture atlas by using appropriate texture coordinates (see glTexCoords) or create 3 textures for your 3 images and perform enable/bind/draw/disable for each texture.

Have a look at TextureIO, AWTTextureIO, glBindTexture, glEnable, glDisable and glTexCoord2f.

Please note that my answer assumes that you use the fixed pipeline but using the programmable pipeline would be preferable on the long term. You should use the retained mode (VAOs, VBOs, ...) even though you use the fixed pipeline instead of the immediate mode (glBegin, glEnd, glVertex, ...) in my humble opinion.